# How to add both Form and List to $this [Plesk/Zend]

Tags: zend-framework, plesk

I have some sample code with 2 tabs.  One shows a "form" and the other a "list" (Sample 1.5-1), I want to combine them.

I want to show the "form" tab with a "list" view at the bottom (after submit button). I am getting stuck on how to show this.

Inside IndexController, in the ->getRequest->isPost() area, I try to create and fill up the $list (same as the "list" tab example code):

```
$list=$this->_getListRandom();
$this->view->list = $list;
```

Then inside of form.phtml, I append:

```
<h1>My Report Data></h1>
<?php echo $this->list; ?>
```

I can see the "My Report Data" text in the web page, so I know I am getting to the right area in the code!
But, I get an error from pm_View_Helper_render::renderList() that it must be an instance of pm_View_List_Simple.

I am trying to create both a pm_Form_Simple and pm_View_List_Simple in the same $this, but not
sure if it is allowed or how to do it.

Thanks for any suggestions!

```
<?php

class IndexController extends pm_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // Init title for all actions
        $this->view->pageTitle = 'Example Module';

        // Init tabs for all actions
        $this->view->tabs = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Form',
                'action' => 'form',
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'List',
                'action' => 'list',
            ),
        );
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // Default action will be formAction
        $this->_forward('form');
    }

    public function formAction()
    {
        // Init form here
        $form = new pm_Form_Simple();
        $form->addElement('text', 'exampleText', array(
            'label' => 'Example Text',
            'value' => pm_Settings::get('exampleText'),
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array('NotEmpty', true),
            ),
        ));

        $form->addControlButtons(array(
            'cancelLink' => pm_Context::getModulesListUrl(),
        ));

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {

            // Form proccessing here
            pm_Settings::set('exampleText', $form->getValue('exampleText'));

            $this->_status->addMessage('info', 'Data was successfully saved.');

            # Create the LIST 
            $list = $this->_getListRandom();
            $this->view->list = $list;

            $this->_helper->json(array('redirect' => pm_Context::getBaseUrl()));
        }

        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $list = $this->_getListRandom();

        // List object for pm_View_Helper_RenderList
        $this->view->list = $list;
    }

    public function listDataAction()
    {
        $list = $this->_getListRandom();

        // Json data from pm_View_List_Simple
        $this->_helper->json($list->fetchData());
    }

    private function _getListRandom()
    {
        $data = array();
        #$iconPath = pm_Context::getBaseUrl() . 'images/icon_16.gif';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
            $data[] = array(
                'column-1' => '<a href="#">' . (string)rand() . '</a>',
                'column-2' => (string)rand(),
            );
        }

        $list = new pm_View_List_Simple($this->view, $this->_request);
        $list->setData($data);
        $list->setColumns(array(
            'column-1' => array(
                'title' => 'Random with link',
                'noEscape' => true,
            ),
            'column-2' => array(
                'title' => 'Random with image',
                'noEscape' => true,
            ),
        ));
        // Take into account listDataAction corresponds to the URL /list-data/
        $list->setDataUrl(array('action' => 'list-data'));

        return $list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you're getting an error from `pm_View_Helper_render`, but that's not called anywhere in the code you posted. Do you call that elsewhere in form.phtml?

Comment: Oops, it must have been cached...(plesk seems to do this).  I don't get any error now, but neither do I get the "list" control...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try https://mega.co.nz/#!NxtyzbyS!JQqFdh7ruESQU_pgmhM6vi8yVFZQRTH-sPDeQcAOFws

Following files are changed:

\example-1.5-2\plib\views\scripts\index\form.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->renderTabs($this->tabs); ?>
<?php echo $this->test; ?>
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
<?php echo $this->renderList($this->list); ?>
```

\example-1.5-2\plib\controllers\IndexController.php:

```
public function formAction() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        $list = $this->_getListRandom();

        // List object for pm_View_Helper_RenderList
        $this->view->list = $list;
}
```

and here the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I have been locked out of myopenid login for days...so just wanted to say big thanks!